# Understanding minecraft custom generation settings

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When you create a new world, you can choose the option of **Custom terrain** (i think that's the name). This options allows to the player generate a custom map with custom values.

There are a tons of settings, and there are some settings I don't understand. 
These settings are the settings that controls the terrain perlin noise.

Last day, I was trying to do a custom terrain, but I don't know how to mmodify these parameters.

- How do they work amd affect to the map?
- What does every single (or a group of these) does?

*Note: I've searched at the minecraft wiki, but the definitions aren't explained clearly for me.*

Comment: This should answer your question: [How do the customized world settings work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165826/how-do-the-customized-world-settings-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Advanced settings:**
**Main Noise Scale X** stretches the terrain along the x-axis, consequently making the terrain more smooth. Larger values for smoother terrain.
**Main Noise Scale Y** stretches the terrain along the y (height) axis. Larger values for smoother, higher and more hilly terrain. Ranges from 1 to 5000, and defaults to 160.
**Main Noise Scale Z** stretches the terrain along the z-axis, consequently making the terrain more smooth. Larger values for smoother terrain. Ranges from 1 to 5000, and defaults to 80.
**Depth Noise Scale X** changes the abruptness of terrain height along the x axis. It ranges from 1 to 2000, and defaults to 200.
**Depth Noise Scale Z** changes the abruptness of terrain height along the z axis. It ranges from 1 to 2000, and defaults to 200.
**Depth Noise Exponent** ranges from 0.01 to 20, and defaults to 0.5. Not quite sure what it does.
**Depth Base Size** changes the base height of land. It ranges from 1 to 25, and defaults to 8.5. 1 in this value corresponds to 8 blocks, so the default is 8.5 * 8, which is 68.
**Coordinate Scale**: Larger values sharpen and create more frequent hills without stretching the biome. It is best used last to tweak the terrain. Ranges from 1 to 6000, and defaults to 684.412.
**Height Scale** stretches the base hills vertically before more details are made. It ranges from 1 to 6000, and defaults to 684.412.
Height Stretch pulls terrain upward, with smaller values causing more extreme stretching. Ranges from 0.01 to 50, and defaults to 12.
**Upper Limit Scale** makes terrain more solid/riddled with holes depending on how close the values are to the lower limit scale values. Ranges from 1 to 5000, and defaults to 512.
**Lower Limit Scale** makes terrain more solid or riddled with holes depending on how close the values are to the upper limit scale values. Ranges from 1 to 5000, and defaults to 512.
**Biome Depth Weight** stretches terrain vertically. All biomes have a number that is added to or subtracted from the Depth Base Size. That number is then multiplied by this field. Ranges from 1 to 20, and defaults to 1.
**Biome Depth Offset** offsets the default terrain level by a specified amount proportional to a power of this field. Ranges from 0 to 20, and defaults to 0.
**Biome Scale Weight** changes how much a biome's settings alter the terrain. Ranges from 1 to 20, and defaults to 1.
**Biome Scale Offset** stretches/squash terrain vertically based on the biomes default height settings. Ranges from 0 to 20, and defaults to 0. Not quite sure what it does.
[My Source of Info](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165826/how-do-the-customized-world-settings-work)